# GitHub Self-Hosted Runners - Cleanup Job

Tags: github, github-actions, github-actions-self-hosted-runners

Want to Cleanup workspace before and after the workflow run on self-hosted runner.
Can provide below mentioned on .env with the cleaupjob.sh.

Did anyone tried this., Can you share the cleanupjob.sh for using on windows and linux self-hosted runners.

ACTIONS_RUNNER_HOOK_JOB_STARTED:
ACTIONS_RUNNER_HOOK_JOB_COMPLETED

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/managing-self-hosted-runners/running-scripts-before-or-after-a-job

Comment: How is someone else's workspace cleanup going to help you? That cleans up _their workspace_. You need to write the script that appropriately cleans up _your workspace_.

Comment: Want to know what’s the script used for cleaning up GitHub workspace. Should be generic as it’s defined at runner configuration.

Comment: No, it's not generic. If you don't actually know what you need to clean up, maybe you don't need to attach a script to this hook at all.

Comment: O ok, I was thinking this script would clear the "<Runner-Folder>/_work/<Github workspace>" before the workflow starts and at the end of workflow.